# SharePoint Designer Automatically Uninstalled By System Account

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a very strange and frustrating situation that I'm hoping someone can help with.

Yesterday morning, SharePoint Designer was automatically uninstalled from my computer by my system account. Weird, I know.

Here's part of the system log that shows the uninstall:

> Log Name: Application
>
> Source: MsiInstaller
>
> Date: 6/11/2020 7:38:29 AM
>
> Event ID: 11724
>
> Task Category: None
>
> Level: Information
>
> Keywords: Classic
>
> User: SYSTEM
>
> Description:
>
> Product: Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 -- Removal completed
>   successfully.

I worked with my company's Helpdesk to get it reinstalled and all seemed to be back to normal. I used it to update a couple of workflows and closed out at the end of the day.

Here's where things get *really* weird, when I went to open the app this morning, it was gone again! This is incredibly challenging and frustrating for me so I'm really hoping someone might have some insight.

If it helps, I'm running Windows 10 v1909.

Comment: It seems strange, generally speaking, SharePoint Designer will not be uninstalled automatically. Check whether some user uninstalled it.

Comment: We opened a ticket with Microsoft and the technician's best guess is that the uninstall was related to a system update. Several other older (2013) "things" were uninstalled too. For example, MUI files. The uninstall definitely wasn't performed by a person. I'm providing detailed logs so they can do a deeper analysis. We'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, if Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP(SPP) does not start, it may uninstall or error when installing SP designer.

Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP(SPP) enables digital licenses for Windows and Windows Applications. If it is not started or errors when starting, it will remove all the Licenses which are flagged.

Here's a link with more information:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a5459947-4fb3-4f56-b2c1-0639441d586d/sharepoint-designer-2013-license-issue?forum=sharepointcustomization